# What is the number of zeroes of $z^4+4z^3+6z^2-4z+3$ inside $|z-1|<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been practicing some problems on Rouche's theorem, but this one has given me trouble.

How can I find how many zeroes of $z^4+4z^3+6z^2-4z+3$ inside $|z-1|<1$?

The given polynomial looks similar to $(z-1)^4=z^4-4z^3+6z^2-4z+1$, so I let $g(z)$ be the given polynomial, and take $f(z)=8z^3+2$. Then on the circle $|z-1|=1$,
$$
|f(z)-g(z)|=|(z-1)^4|=|z-1|^4=1.
$$
If I could show $|f(z)|>1$ on the curve, then I would have that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeroes inside the circle, which I think is zero for $f$. Is this the right idea, or have I gone astray? Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Schur-CohnAlgorithm.html), [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_stability_criterion) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9's_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two of the four complex roots are inside the unit circle centered at $1$.
If you find these two pairs of conjugate roots, you can work out that
$$
g(z)\approx(x^2+4.64751368404x+8.66302952977)(x^2-0.647513684039x+0.346299177406)
$$
and that the roots are approximately
$$
\{
-2.32375684201972 \pm 1.80642842895505 i,~
 0.32375684201972 \pm 0.491406842291623 i
\},
$$
the former pair of which lie outside and the latter pair inside the given circle.
However, I needed a numerical method to obtain the above and haven't used Rouche's theorem; I like your approach...I'll consider how to proceed...

In fact, $f(z)=2(4z^3+1)$ has roots at $-\frac1{\sqrt[3]{4}}\,e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{3}}$ for $k=0,\pm1$ along the circle of radius $2^{-\frac23}$, two of which are inside $|z-1|=1$ since
$$\left|1+\frac1{\sqrt[3]{4}}\,e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right|<1.$$
(For $k=\pm1$, the roots are on the side of a unit equilateral triangle stemming radially from the origin, which is thus inside the unit circle centered at $1$.)

Also, on the unit circle in question,
if we let $z=1+e^{it}$
following @RobertIsrael's lead, then
$$
\eqalign{
h(t)&=
\left|
f(z)
\right|^2
=4\cdot
\left|
4\left(1+e^{it}\right)^3+1
\right|^2
=4\cdot
\left|
5+12e^{it}+12e^{2it}+4e^{3it}
\right|^2
\\&
=4\cdot
\left[
\left(5+12\cos{t}+12\cos{2t}+4\cos{3t}\right)^2+4\,
\left(   3\sin{t}+ 3\sin{2t}+ \sin{3t}\right)^2
\right]
\\&
=4\cdot
\Big[
(5^2+12^2+12^2+4^2) + 2\cdot5\cdot4\, \left(3\cos{t}+3\cos{2t}+\cos{3t}\right)
\Big.\\&\qquad\Big.
+2\cdot4^2\cdot3\,\left(3\cos{(2t-t)}+\cos{(3t-t)}+\cos{(3t-2t)}\right)
\Big]
\qquad\text{(combining pairwise terms)}
\\&
=4\cdot
\left[
329
+ 8\, \left(15\cos{t}+15\cos{2t}+5\cos{3t}\right)
+ 8\, \left(48\cos{t}+12\cos{2t}\right)
\right]
\\&
=4\cdot
\left[
329
+ 8\, \left(63\cos{t}+27\cos{2t}+5\cos{3t}\right)
\right]
}
$$
by expanding the squares,
combining pairwise terms and using
$\cos(a-b)=$ $\cos a\cos b+$$\sin a\sin b$
with $a,b\in\{t,2t,3t\}$.
Differentiating and using the double & triple angle formulas
(or [$U_1,~U_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Examples)$\in\mathbb{Z}[\cos t]$),
$$
\eqalign{
h'(t)&
=-96\,
\left[
21\sin{t}+18\sin{2t}+5\sin{3t}
\right]
\\&=
-96\,\sin t\,
\left[
       21
     + 18 \left( 2\cos t \right)
     + 5 \left( 4 \cos^2t - 1 \right)
\right]
\\&=
-96\,\sin t\,
\left[ 20 \cos^2t
     + 36 \cos t
     + 16
\right]
\\&=
-384\,\sin t\,
\left(   \cos t + 1 \right)
\left( 5 \cos t + 4 \right)
}
$$
we obtain the critical points
and find the global minimum
as he did in his comment,
showing that $|f(z)|\ge\frac65$
on the circle in question.

[image]

So now you can use Rouché's theorem.

Comment: Thanks bgins, so there are two roots inside the unit circle centered at 1. Do you know if it's possible to show $|f(z)|>1$ on the circle though, so that Rouche's theorem actually applies? I haven't been able to manage that.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some subtlety, isn't it needed to show $|f(z)|>1$ on the circle $|z-1|=1$, not $|z|=1$, since the calculation that $|f(z)-g(z)|<1$ was done on $|z-1|=1$?

Comment: oops. sorry. give me a minute...

Comment: Yes, I get the following (with Maple's help):
$$ |f(1+\exp(it))|^2 = 1316+2016 \cos(t)+864 \cos(2t)+160 \cos(3t)$$
and the critical points of this in $[-\pi,\pi]$ are at $t=0, \pm \arccos(-4/5), \pm \pi$.  The minimum is $36/25$ at $t = \pm \arccos(-4/5)$.

Comment: Thanks for the check, @RobertIsrael.

Comment: Yes, thanks @RobertIsrael. Just out of curiosity, (since I know you're a Maple guru...) did Maple do that on its own, or did you need to knudge it a little?

Comment: Not much nudging.  You can do something like this:

> f := z -> 8*z^3+2:
> Q := evalc(abs(f(1+exp(I*t)))^2):
> solve(diff(Q,t)=0,t,AllSolutions);

Then you recognize that it's enough to take _Z1 to be $0$ or $1$ and the other _Zi parameters to be $0$.